# On click for shiny inputs to get last input clicked doesn't work for selectInput or selectizeInput

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I want to trigger a reactive containing the input id of the last input clicked. What I have works fine for some inputs like `numericInput` and `textInput`. But it doesn't work for `selectInput` or `selectizeInput`. I've tried using a variety of selectors in the JS expression, but none are capturing `selectInput` or `selectizeInput`.

Here's a reprex. When you click on either of the first two inputs, the renderText updates, but it doesn't with the last two.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(
      htmlwidgets::JS("$( document ).on('click', '.form-control, .shiny-bound-input, .selectized', function() {
                        Shiny.setInputValue('last_input', this.id);
                      });")
    )
  ),
  
  numericInput("num1", "Numeric", 0),
  textInput("text1", "Text"),
  selectInput("select1", "Select", choices = LETTERS[1:4]),
  selectInput("selectize1", "Selectize", choices = letters[1:4]),
  
  textOutput("textout")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$textout <- renderText({
    input$last_input
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I tried this more generic JS expression and it also didn't work:
`$(document).ready(function(){
                              $('input').on('click', function(evt){
                                Shiny.setInputValue('last_input', evt.target.id);
                              });
                            })`

Comment: Looking in Developer Tools, it seems that shiny's select and selectize has `display: none`, so it won't trigger a click: `<select id="select1" tabindex="-1" class="selectized shiny-bound-input" style="display: none;"><option value="A" selected="selected">A</option></select>`

Answer (score 0):

That's because the id is attributed to the `select` element and you don't click this element.

My first idea was to search for the first parent element having an id:

```
tags$script(
  HTML("$( document ).on('click', '.form-control, .shiny-bound-input, .selectized', function() {
          var $parentWithId = $(this).closest('*[id]');
          Shiny.setInputValue('last_input', $parentWithId.attr('id'));
        });")
)
```

but that still doesn't work for `selectizeInput`.

Maybe you rather want:

```
tags$script(
  HTML("$(document).on('shiny:inputchanged', function(event) {
          Shiny.setInputValue('last_input', event.name);
        });")
)
```

which returns the id of the last changed input.

---

## EDIT

As you noted in your comment, this method also sets `last_input` when the change is caused from the server by an `update*` function. Here is how to prevent that:

```
tags$script(
  HTML("$(document)
         .on('shiny:updateinput', function(e) {
            $(e.target).one('shiny:inputchanged', function(ev) {
              ev.stopPropagation();
            });
          })
          .on('shiny:inputchanged', function(e) {
            Shiny.setInputValue('last_input', e.name);
          });")
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't work for my case. I'm trying to use the last input clicked to determine whether a user changed the input versus whether it changed via an update* function. Your suggestion would result it triggering for both cases.

Comment: @WillHipson You're right. But one can prevent that - please see my edit.

Comment: Is there anywhere I can find more info/examples on using JS to stop an update* function from invalidating and triggering a reactive? It would help me to bypass creating a `last_input` reactive altogether.

Comment: Created a separate issue specifically for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72101238/stop-updateinput-from-invalidating-reactive

Comment: I was unable to get this solution working. Turns out I needed to exclude the `'last_input'` value from the JaveScript. You can find my clarifying question and its answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75395277/7742981

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after a while, I found the solution. First of all, you must identify the beginning string of the selectInput **id**: let's assume that the id begins by the string **id_name**. Shiny selectInput is contained in a **div** that changes when one clicks on the input, and it is after the click that the selectected value is assigned to **select** element which contains the input id named **id**. To get the **id** of selectInput when clicking on the input, you have to apply jquery change-event when the **div** changes by doing this:

```
tags$head(
tags$script(
HTML(
"$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div').on('change', 'select',function(evt){
    if(evt.target.id.match('^id_name')=='id_name'){
        Shiny.setInputValue('select_id', evt.target.id);
    }
  });
});"
)
)
)
```