# Shiny does not detect shiny:inputchanged event

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

The approach I am taking for my shiny app design would be easiest if the app could detect the ID of the last clicked or updated widget.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72061061/7742981) question appears to solve the problem. However, when I run the MCVE with the accepted answer I get no reactivity at all.

Current code as follows. This is essentially the linked question with the obvious substitution made from the accepted answer.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    # taken from accepted answer
    tags$script(
      HTML("$(document).on('shiny:inputchanged', function(event) {
          Shiny.setInputValue('last_input', event.name);
        });")
    )
    # through to here
  ),
  
  numericInput("num1", "Numeric", 0),
  textInput("text1", "Text"),
  selectInput("select1", "Select", choices = LETTERS[1:4]),
  selectInput("selectize1", "Selectize", choices = letters[1:4]),
  
  textOutput("textout")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$textout <- renderText({
    input$last_input
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Expected behavior:

- When the widgets are interacted with, then the id of the last widget interacted with is displayed.

Observed behavior:

- Regardless of which widget I interact with, no widget ids are displayed.

Checked tried:

- Updating Shiny version.
- The other code suggestions on the original post - no change
- Some, but not full, reactivity from using ...`.ready(function(){$('input').on('shiny:inputchanged'`... instead of just `.on('shiny:inputchanged'`.

I am an R, not a JS, programmer. Can someone with both skills can advise how to get this working?

Comment: A warning to those who adopt this method: `shiny:inputchanged` captures __every__ change. This includes conditional panels and widget creation. Even with the fix from @ismirsehregal, for more complex apps detecting other changes makes it is very easy to get stuck in an endless loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to exclude the input, which is set in the JS part regarding the events to monitor, otherwise you'll end up in an endless loop.

Please check my related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56770222/get-the-event-which-is-fired-in-shiny/56771353#56771353):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(
      "$(document).on('shiny:inputchanged', function(event) {
          if (event.name != 'changed') {
            Shiny.setInputValue('changed', event.name);
          }
        });"
    )
  ),
  numericInput("num1", "Numeric", 0),
  textInput("text1", "Text"),
  selectInput("select1", "Select", choices = LETTERS[1:4]),
  selectInput("selectize1", "Selectize", choices = letters[1:4]),
  
  textOutput("textout")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$textout <- renderText({
    input$changed
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[Here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/js-events.html) the according documentation can be found.